# Maximum dynamic pressure upon Mars entry

Tags: mars, reentry, landing, entry-descent-landing

I have a Mars landing simulation, and one of the things it calculates is the dynamic pressure as the spacecraft descends through Mars' thin atmosphere (given by $q=\frac{1}{2}\rho v^{2}$). I know it depends on many different parameters such as the atmospheric model used to find $\rho$ vs. altitude and of course the velocity that you have as you enter Mars, but I was wondering if anyone has any data regarding dynamic pressures experienced by spacecraft entering Mars' atmosphere.

Comment: For the MERs it was around 5 to 5.5 kPa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical rigid mid L/D aeroshell indicated in Mars exploration architecture encounters a maximum dynamic pressure of 11 kPa.

[image: Rigid Mid L/D aeroshell of Ares V type]

While, Hypersonic Inflatable Aerodynamic Decelerator would encounter a maximum entry dynamic pressure of 4.24 kPa.

[image: HIAD]

Also, for mid L/D aeroshell based entry vehicles of Ares V kind, (Pg. 14)

> The aerodynamic model covers Mach 1.3 through 50, angles of attack of 0 through 90o, and dynamic pressures of 1.E-7 through 0.75 bars

I'm not entirely sure if it is reasonable to infer that max dynamic pressures of 0.1 - 0.75 bar are involved.

[***Entry, Descent and Landing Systems Analysis Study: Phase 1 Report***](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20100026676.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

For [MSL (Curiosity), the expected peak dynamic pressure was 15.4 kPa](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20090007730.pdf). (table 8)

I don't know how typical of Mars entries that is.